# How to start with writing extension apps for Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, appexchange, isv, marketing-cloud-connect

I'm an experienced Salesforce developer who build countless AppExchange apps in the last years. But I am absolutely new to Marketing Cloud. I know what it is and how it is used but have no idea on how to develop for it and on it.

I would like to build standalone or integration apps that connect to external systems (e.g. media content providers for Content Builder).

I know there are some APIs and proprietary languages, but I even struggled with step #1: getting a Marketing Cloud Developer Org.

Comment: MC Sandboxes are not free. With January 2020 release they will be discontinued entirely. Therefore, there are and will be no free / dev MC environments available.

Comment: If you get a developer version i am sure there will be countless of other people that would like to have this information too. I have not found any method to get one, either you have a partnership with salesforce and create limitless business units or you may have a non profit organisation that gives you the freedom to use their BU when you contribute to their goals. Other than that: Just buy one :D

Comment: 5+ years and counting: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l1yFAAQ

Comment: Maybe year 6 is our year! *Fingers crossed*

Comment: If you're a registered partner, you can try putting in a request (read: jumping through hoops) for a [Marketing Cloud Partner demo account](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317528&type=1&mode=1).